# Historical data about rock climbing / bouldering ascents

Tags: rock-climbing, bouldering, history

I am always interested in the history of rock climbing. Lately, I tried to collect data about male and female first ascents to visualize progression in rock climbing over time (I have a small blog [Climbstat](http://climbstat.blogspot.com) writing about climbing data and statistics). See below for some visualizations of the data I could collect so far. However, it turned out difficult to find a lot of data especially for female climbers. An exception to the rule is this nice [source](http://stara.emontana.cz/climbing-milestones-from-6a-to-9c/) from which I borrowed a lot of information.

Do you have any idea where I can find additional data about first ascents? I would be especially interested in first onsights / flashes, information about first bouldering ascents as well as information about early first female ascents (such as first female 7a, 7a+, ...).

[image]
[image]

Comment: You could also try asking on [opendata.se]. You will need to explain some of the rock climbing specific terms for that audience (like, define exactly what a "first ascent" is).

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if you're still looking for information on this but the Pinnacle Club (the UK's first women's rock climbing club) have just celebrated their centenary and have put together a website with lots of information and archival footage from the past century. [This webpage](https://www.pc100.org/firsts-and-notable-achievements) in particular has a lot of female firsts, although it may be earlier in climbing history than what you're looking for.